# Bazel - How to create Deps for a Rule from dynamic list of targest directories

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-python

I want to create `deps` in a rule in Bazel that will be dynamic and not hardcoded, from a list of directories.

Here is the file structure:

```
|   //plugins_folder
├── code0.py
├── BUILD
├── plugin1
|   ├── BUILD
|   ├── code1-0.py
|   ├── code1-1.py
├── plugin2
|   ├── BUILD
|   ├── code2-0.py
|   ├── code2-1.py
```

File0.py depends on file1-0.py and file2-0.py

I want the `BUILD` file in the root to use the `BUILD` files in the plugins without adding them explicitly to the root `BUILD`, but to calculate the `deps` dynamically

The root `BUILD` file should behave like this:

```
py_library(
    name = "code0",
    srcs = ["code0.py"],
    deps = ["//plugin1:code1-0", "//plugin1:code1-1", "//plugin1:code2-0", "//plugin1:code2-1"]
)
```

But instead of having the `deps` above to hardcoded, I want to get them dynamically.

Something like this (obviously, it does not work as glob does not retrieve targets but files):

```
py_library(
    name = "code0",
    srcs = ["code0.py"],
    deps = [":%s" % x[:-3] for x in glob(["**/*.py"])],
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [subpackages](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/toplevel/native#subpackages) or better yet `subpackages` from the future compatible [bazel_skylib](https://registry.bazel.build/modules/bazel_skylib)

```
py_library(
    name = "all_plugins",
    srcs = ["some_source.py"],
    deps = [
        "//plugins_folder/%s:all" % subpkg for subpkg in subpackages(include=["plugin*"])
    ],
)
```

Verify you have all the dependencies using:
`bazel query 'deps(//plugin_folder:all_plugins)'`

Comment: Thank you! The ':all' does not work. But the concept is working!